# How to open overlay menu from oncomplete of p:commandButton with Primefaces?

Tags: primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 3.3.1 and have question.

I have p:commandButton inside p:column of p:dataTable. I can show overlay menu when button is clicked with xhtml shown below.

```
    <p:commandButton id="btnID" icon="ui-icon-circle-triangle-s" style="height: 16px;">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{searchItem}" target="#{bean.selectedSearchItem}" />
    </p:commandButton>
    <p:slideMenu overlay="true" trigger="btnID" my="left top" at="left bottom"
            model="#{bean.menuModel}"/>
```

In this case, bean.menuModel can return menu data instantly. But I have another case also which pre-procsessing is required to make menu data ready. So I have this one too.

```
    <p:commandButton ajax="true" id="historyButton" action="#{bean.getHistory()}"
        icon="ui-icon-note" style="height: 16px;"
        onstart="workingDialog.show();"
        oncomplete="workingDialog.hide(); historyMenu.show();"> 
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{searchItem}" target="#{bean.selectedSearchItem}" />
    </p:commandButton>
    <p:menu overlay="true" widgetVar="historyMenu" my="left top" at="left bottom"
            model="#{searchBean.menuModel}"/>
```

What I meant is, when button is clicked, it calls bean.getHistory() which starts loading menu data for that row, and show modal dialog with circling icon. When loading is finished, dialog will go away and overlay menu will be shown. What I can't do is a last part of this scenario. Above code fires exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.findComponent(UIComponentBase.java:561)
    org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer.encodeOverlayConfig(BaseMenuRenderer.java:138)
    org.primefaces.component.menu.MenuRenderer.encodeScript(MenuRenderer.java:45)
    org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(BaseMenuRenderer.java:39)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1763)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
```

Code shown below works fine, without menu related code.

```
    <p:commandButton ajax="true" id="historyButton" action="#{searchBean.getHistory()}"
        icon="ui-icon-note" style="height: 16px;"
        onstart="workingDialog.show();"
        oncomplete="workingDialog.hide();"> 
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{searchItem}" target="#{bean.selectedSearchItem}" />
    </p:commandButton>
```

I guess this is easy question for experts. How can I open overlay menu from oncomplete?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a solution for this issue but I came up with conclusion that what I wanted to do is not a good idea with the environment I'm working on.

First, I noticed that menu gets data from bean when row of data table is populated, not when menu is shown. And there is no lazy loading mechanism for menu. So button click -> get data for menu from server -> open menu cannot be done as I expected (at least it seems to me).

Second, I noticed putting menu in DataTable (under TabView in my case) causes very strange problem. When I update DataTable, some ajax related function stops working. I can't explain this problem to make you understand or believe, but app I'm working on is having this problem.

So, I gave up putting menu in DataTable in my app. Thank you for your attention.

I accept this answer not to lower my already LOW accept rate.